# Using data-callback in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When using for example `<div data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>`, the function recaptchaCallback is executed using

```
<script>
function recaptchaCallback() {
    alert('OK');
}
</script>
```

The above code works, and I get an Alertbox with "OK".

However I need to achieve this within Vue, in order to be able to send the data on the callback in an Ajax request from within vue.

**How would I achieve this within Vue, so that when I get the callback, I can execute code within Vue with this data?**

Answer (score -1):

Put the function in a separate js file and import it into a component.

```
// alert.js 
const alert = function recaptchaCallback(data) {
    alert('OK');
    // do something with data...
}
export default alert

// my-component.vue
import alert from 'path/to/alert.js'
...
methods: {
    onSomeAction (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @btl, thansk for your answer. How can I import this from another file, if the file with alert is gulp'ed?

Comment: Ive tried to play around with the code, but I cant seem to get it to work at all